# vue.js app.$destroy() does not remove app instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, dom-events, destroy

I am learning vue js. I  have an app called *growler*. I am trying to call `$destroy` method *on-click* of button.

```
<button id="destroyButton" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="onDestroyClick">Destroy</button>
```

If I have method as part of Javascript event, it is working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           document.getElementById('destroyButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                growler.$destroy();
            }); 
</script>
```

But, if I call this method as part of vue *on-click* event, it is not working.

```
methods: {
                  onDestroyClick: function() {
                        this.$destroy();
                    } 
                }
```

I am having lifecycle hooks for different events of the instance. I am trying to log them in the console.

```
beforeDestroy: function() {
                    console.log('beforeDestroy');
                },

                destroyed: function() {
                    console.log('afterDestroy');
                }
```

This is working fine from Javascript Event listener. I am able to see Destroy messages in the console log.

Can you please tell, why it is not working as part of on-click event method. App instance is not destroyed.

Comment: is `$destroy()` being applied on the root Vue instance ?

Comment: @JacobGoh yes. I tried with growler.$destroy() also, inside onDestroyClick function. It did not work :(

Comment: When I tested it in https://jsfiddle.net/u157emcr/3/ , the DOM element would stay the same after destroyed. How did you judge whether the app was destroyed or not? Your Vue code seems fine and bugless.

Comment: I am having method for different lifecycle hooks: `beforeDestroy: function() {
                    console.log('beforeDestroy');
                },

                destroyed: function() {
                    console.log('afterDestroy');
                }` <br /> I am not seeing destroy logs in the Console

Comment: In that case, the bug is probably not included in the info you provided. Try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) jsfilddle ?

Comment: @JacobGoh, I have updated the question. I will try with jsfiddle. thanks.

Comment: @JacobGoh, There seems to a problem with braces. It is working fine now in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u157emcr/12/). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the answer here, as it was just mentioned in the comments.

It was a problem with bracces. The code is pasted below:

The corresponding jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u157emcr/12/)

```js
    var growler = new Vue({
                    el: '#growler',
                    data :
                    {
                     message : "test"
                    },

                    methods: {                   
                        onDestroyClick: function() {
                            this.$destroy();
                        } 
                    },
                   beforeDestroy: function() {
                       console.log('beforeDestroy');;
                    },

                    afterDestroy: function() {
                        console.log('afterDestroy');
                    } 
                    });
```